# Getting any error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip on user registration

Tags: python, html

I'm creating a user registration using django. I have created a simple HTML file with my view register. But when I click submit it is giving me an error:

```
email_name, domain_part = email.strip().split('@', 1)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

My HTML:

```
<form action="register" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter ur nem"><br>
<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter ur surname"><br>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter ur email"><br>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter ur Usetrname"><br>
<input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Enter ur password"><br>
<input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Enter again your password"><br>
<input type="submit"> </div>
```

My view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User , auth
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
 first_name= request.POST['first_name'],
    last_name= request.POST['last_name'],
    email= request.POST['email'],
    password1 = request.POST['password1'],
    password2= request.POST['password2'],
    username= request.POST['username'],

    if password1 == password2:
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            print('usernem taken')
        else:
            myuser= User.objects.create_user(username=username, password = password1, email= email, 
             first_name = first_name, last_name= last_name)
            myuser.save();
            print ('user saved')
    else:
        print('passwords do not match')
    return redirect ('/')
```

Comment: A `string` has a `strip` method. A tuple does not.  The trailing commas are turning all those variables into tuples..  They aren't innocent line ending characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By ending lines like `first_name= request.POST['first_name'],` with commas, `first_name` is not a string as you seem to expect; it is, in fact, a tuple with one element. You may see this if you do something like:

```
>>> t = "test_string",
>>> t
('test_string',)
```

You then get an error as you try to call `strip` on the tuple, rather than a string.

To fix this problem, you need to remove the trailing commas on all of the lines extracting values from `request.POST`, so

```
email= request.POST['email'],
```

becomes

```
email = request.POST['email']
```